# Dropwizard service directory inside assets directory

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, assets, dropwizard

I have a Dropwizard/AngularJS website. I have my assets served from an AssetsBundle on the root directory:

```
public void initialize(Bootstrap<WebsiteConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/", "/", "index.html"));
    ...
}
```

And I want to serve my REST endpoints on /services:

```
public void run(WebsiteConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/service");
    ...
}
```

Based on documentation and answers I've seen elsewhere, this seems like it should work. However, I just tried it, and everything on /service is returning a 404. When I dug into the app through a debugger, it appears that it's because the requests are going through the AssetServlet, not through Jersey.

Am I missing something? Is there a good way to serve my front-end on the root directory and the REST services on a sub-path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this issue some time ago. What helped me was adding these lines to the `app.yml` config file:

```
server:
  type: simple
  rootPath: '/rest/*'
  applicationContextPath: /
```

Comment: That did it. Although I looked into it, you don't need to set the type to simple in newer versions of Dropwizard, applicationContextPath and rootPath work with a default server.